# How to shut down Spring Boot Kafka stream-processing app after current message

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-function

In a Spring Boot Kafka stream-processing app using Spring Cloud Function, how can I shut down the application (to stop it receiving any further messages) but only after responding to the current message?

The scenario is this: we have an app that processes a message which contains a reference to some file. We handle this by interrogating the given file's content using some third party libraries and responding with some data we extract from the file. In some rare cases certain files can cause the external libraries to hang. So we call these libraries on a background thread and time out if it takes too long. We need to respond to Kafka for this message (with some JSON detailing the error) so that Kafka doesn't send it to any other instance of our app (as it'll probably cause that instance to hang as well). But we then want this instance of our Spring Boot app to shut down, as we can't cleanly recover from the hang in the 3rd party library (we could get resource or memory leaks otherwise). Another instance will then be automatically brought up by Kubernetes or Docker Swarm or whatever.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but we're using Spring Cloud Function, and we're joining two streams: the "file" stream, where each message contains a reference to the file to process, and a GlobalKTable with some config info. The code looks like this (in Kotlin):

```
    // The service we use to run the process on a background thread
    private val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)

    @Bean
    fun process() = BiFunction<KStream<String, FileInfo>,
        GlobalKTable<String, Config>,
        KStream<String, FileInterrogationResult>> { fileStream, configTable ->

        requestStream.join(
            configTable,
            { _, file -> file.configId },
            { file, config ->
                try {
                    // Process the file using the 3rd party libraries.
                    val result = executorService.submit(theThirdPartyLibExtractionFunction)
                        .get(someTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

                    // Success: return some FileInterrogationResult object wrapping the result from above.
                } catch (e: TimeoutException) {
                    // Return some FileInterrogationResult object with error details.
                    // TODO: Here we know that after this function completes the app should shut down. How do we do this?
                } catch (e: Throwable) {
                    // Return some FileInterrogationResult object with error details.
                }
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Actuator endpoints to stop/start/pause/resume as well as monitor individual bindings.
Once enabled you can simply use `curl` to manage the bindings.
For example

```
curl -d '{"state":"STOPPED"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://<host>:<port>/actuator/bindings/myBindingName
```

The exact instruction on how to do it available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding_visualization_control)

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Unfortunately it's more that we need to do it programmatically immediately when we encounter the timeout (where the TODO in the code snippet above is). Otherwise either we don't respond to Kafka, in which case another consumer will pick up the message and hang as well. Or we do respond to Kafka but don't shut down, in which case this current instance of the app will receive another message when it hasn't cleaned up from the previous request.

Comment: So just to check: are you suggesting that, where that TODO is in the code snippet above, the Spring Boot app make an HTTP POST request to itself?

Comment: I am not sure i understand your use case so I can't answer the "when/where" question. I just showed you a mechanism by which you can manage the bindings lifecycle. What would be better if you instead explain the business problem so we can find a right solution rather then ask how to enable specific solution which can very well be the wrong one.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the original post provided that info. We basically have the potential for a message which is a "poison pill" (though not because it can't be deserialised). When we process that message it hangs our consumer. So we want to respond to that message (so it doesn't get re-sent to another instance of our consumer). Then we want to shut down our consumer (the whole Spring Boot app in a Docker container) as it's now in an unstable state. Kubernetes will then fire up a new instance of the service, which will pick up the next message and resume as normal.

Comment: So, yes you can POST to stop the binding as described earlier. Given that we already expose this functionality via REST we can perhaps consider exposing it via API for cases like this, so feel free raise an issue and link to this post

Comment: Thanks! Logged here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2096